# how to place place result in angular component in groups of 3

Tags: angular, typescript

so i have an array of objects that return for example 9 objects. in the html i want to show result in 3 grids per row. something like

```
  <li *ngFor="how to put a loop here ? let hero of heroes">
    <div class="row">
   <div>{{ heroes[0] }}<div> <div>{{ heroes[1] }}<div> <div>{{ heroes[2] }}<div>
    </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div>{{ heroes[3] }}<div> <div>{{ heroes[4] }}<div> <div>{{ heroes[5] }}<div>
    </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div>{{ heroes[6] }}<div> <div>{{ heroes[7] }}<div> <div>{{ heroes[8] }}<div>
    </div>
 </li>
```

how can i put such an *ngFor ?
its not a fixed length array.

Comment: Bootstrap 4? and you mean 3 cols per row?

Comment: i updated the question. actually its not a fixed length array. what ever comes from back end i have to divide it into group of 3 in one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution working good with me. you can save new heroes array in variable like _hereos and use it in ngFor. you can review this code live in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vxk7ea).

```
  heroes = [2,3,6,7,8,8];

  createHeroesArray() {
    const arr = [];

    for(let i = 0 , len = this.heroes.length; i < len ; i += 3) {
      arr.push([this.heroes[i],this.heroes[i + 1], this.heroes[i + 2]])
    }

    return arr;
  }
```

```
<li *ngFor="let heroe of createHeroesArray();">
    <div class="row">
        <div>{{ heroe[0] }}</div> 
        <div>{{ heroe[1] }}</div>
        <div>{{ heroe[2] }}</div>
    </div>
 </li>
```